# Invertible sheaves of higher rank

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral Noetherian scheme, let $F$ be a locally free sheaf of finite rank on $X$. Under what conditions is it true that there exists a locally free sheaf of finite rank $G$ on $X$ such that $F\otimes_{O_X}G\approx O_X^{\oplus d}$ as $O_X$-modules for some $d>0$?